# std::cin is not blocking when process is forked

Tags: c++, cin

I have a C++ console application which forks itself and closes the main process.
std::cin in the childprocess is not blocking anymore if a press any key. This results in an endless loop. If I don't fork before then the application behaves as expected.

I have tried different combinations of cin::ignore, cin::fail, cin::clear and close to get this fixed but without success.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Why this is happening and how can I fix that?

```cpp
/* includes */
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits>

void fork_to_background()
{
    pid_t f_return = fork();
    if (f_return == -1)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (f_return != 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fork_to_background();

    std::string commands;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> commands;
        std::cout << "Loop" << std::endl;

        //std::cin.clear();
        //std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*std::cin >> commands;* does not block when you reach EOF, you can see it checking if >> success, for instance

```
if (! std::cin >> commands) {
   std::cout << "EOF" << std::endl;
   break;
}
```

the two lines you put in comment are useless here because you read a string, they are useful in case you read for instance a number and the input is not a valid number

note the parent process exit immediately after the *fork*, closing *stdin* for the child because they share *stdin*

if I modify your program to have :

```
/* includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void fork_to_background()
{
    pid_t f_return = fork();
    if (f_return == -1)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (f_return != 0)
    {
        waitpid(f_return, NULL, 0); // wait end of child
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fork_to_background();

    std::string commands;

    while(std::cin >> commands)
    {
      std::cout << commands << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Loop" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -Wall f.cc
/tmp % echo "aze qsd" | ./a.out
aze
Loop
qsd
Loop
done
/tmp %
```

Comment: I'm not piping any file to the application and not pressing Ctrl-D. Why I'm getting EOF?

Comment: @artem.metra because the parent exit immediately closing stdin, I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware that stdin is always closed because the parent process is exited. With this in mind I could solve the problem :).